# .minecraft and %appdata%

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

i have looked at tons of tutorials and stuff, and even looked at other responses, but I still can't find .minecraft and %appdata%. I tried using run, reinstalling the launcher, etc, but nothing helps.

Comment: go into the appdata folder. .minecraft is in the appdata folder. turn on "show hidden" to see appdata

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have windows because you've tried `run`.

Check where your Minecraft profiles are saved in the Launcher:

Under `Installations` find your version and click edit in the dropdown menu to the right of the version.

Then check where your `Game Directory` is saved:
[image: Game directory]

If it says: `<Use default directory>` it should be in your `AppData\Roaming` folder.

The easiest way to find the folder is by using the `run` then typing `%appdata%` and hit enter:
[image: Run]

You should then find the `.minecraft` folder at the top:
[image: folder]

If this doesn't work you can try to search for it in the explorer window:
[image: Eplorer]

It might help to enable `view: Hidden items`:
[image: Hidden items]